# why the tf.transformPoint is giving tf exception?

Tags: ros, transformations, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to transform a point from a base_link frame to camera frame. When run the below code getting error message "**Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.** canTransform returned after 4.003 timeout was 4.Requested time 1466110388.818536997 but the latest data is at time 3101.240000000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [wide_stereo_optical_frame].
target = "wide_stereo_optical_frame"; 
point = PointStamped()
point.point.x =2;
point.point.y = 1;
point.point.z = 1;
point.header.frame_id = "base_link";
point.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now(); 
tl_ = tf.TransformListener();
tl_.waitForTransform(target, point.header.frame_id, rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(5.0));
camera_target = tf.transformPoint(target, point)

botf base_link and wide_stereo_optical_frame  frames are available in tf database. I verified the in the terminal like this 
**rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /wide_stereo_optical_frame**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237270/why-the-tf.transformpoint-is-giving-tf-exception?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-06-16**:
Is this still a problem after you resolved: http://answers.ros.org/question/237248/why-rospy-time-always-prining-zero/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved after referring to this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/35908/using-tf-to-transform-a-point/).
The workaround is, I used a sleep function after tfObject creation.

tl_ = tf.TransformListener();
rospy.sleep(10.)                     
   # The above sleep function gives the sufficient time to load frames from /tf topic

---

Originally posted by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) with karma: 75 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-06-20**:
Did you have to wait 10 second to catch your tf transform?
That is weird in most of the applications, but ok..

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-06-29**:
I tried running my node in a faster computer. It's working fine now without sleep()

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2017-11-23**:
I'm having the exact same problem, but this did not work :/